# angularjs ie8 error : no module found in ie8 but working fine in ie9

Tags: angularjs

I am using the *AngularJS 1.2.9* version.

My site is working fine in IE9 and other browsers but in IE8 it's giving me this error:

```
[$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/nomod?p0=moduleName
```

I am auto-bootstrapping the module from my script.
I have adopted everything from the AngularJS site for IE compatibility: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Why is this error occurring only in IE8 but not in IE9?

Comment: Have you used `id="ng-app"` where you have written `ng-app="optionalModuleName"` ?

Comment: If yes, then check the browser console. You will get the error.

Comment: yes, i am using id="ng-app" and auto bootstrapping the module from my script code.And my console is giving error above.My doubt is that it is working fine in ie9.

Comment: @rajeshpanwar - have you found solution? I met the same problem today.

Comment: Hi Artur, This error was occurring because my javascript code was breaking in ie8.I had been using javascript function that were not supported in ie8. So my module defining code was breaking and angularjs was giving this error. Please like this question to get better answer from other user.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you found solution, but here is a one tip for official angularjs documentation:

AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie